# How to read back data from LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Once checkbox is active there are various `<p>` tags that get class **"result"**. What I do with them is following:

```
function submit(){
  alert("in submit");
  var user_choice = document.getElementsByClassName("result");
  for (var i = 0; i < user_choice.length; i++){
    console.log(user_choice[i].innerHTML);
  }
  localStorage.setItem('storage',user_choice);
}
```

I hope this makes an HTMLcollection. After that, at submitted.html page (redirect there after pressing submit button) I wanna `console.log` all the items. So I write this:

```
window.onload = function() {
  if ( localStorage.getItem('storage')) {
    var got_user_choice = localStorage.getItem('storage');
    for (var i = 0; i < got_user_choice.length; i++){
      console.log(got_user_choice[i].innerHTML);
    }
 }
}
```

As long as it's a HTMLcollection (read array) I operate with it in terms of array. But what I get in console is just `undefined`. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: localStorage saves in the form of objects not arrays

Comment: @AshayMandwarya No, LocalStorage is strings only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

Answer (score 4):

Local storage can only contain strings, not DOM elements. You should make an array of all the elements, and convert that to JSON.

```
function submit(){
  alert("in submit");
  var user_choice = document.getElementsByClassName("result");
  var html = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < user_choice.length; i++){
    console.log(user_choice[i].innerHTML);
    html.push(user_choice[i].innerHTML);
  }
  localStorage.setItem('storage',JSON.stringify(html));
}
```